# What does "lifeline" mean in football context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "lifeline" mean in football/soccer context?

Early drama at Ewood Park.

We're barely 20 seconds into the game and Sam Mcallums has just delivered a cross into the box but it skims across the top of the bar!

**Lifeline** for Rovers.

Comment: To be clear "lifeline" in this exact same context could be used in any sporting any event when the other team still has a chance. It is not specific to just football/soccer.

Comment: It's not even specific to sports. It's a metaphor for an actual lifeline that applies any time there's a reversal or reprieve in a dire situation.

Comment: Also, 20 seconds into a game hardly merits the term "lifeline". The announcer is embellishing.

Answer (score 1):

**lifeline**: noun [ C ]

a rope that is thrown to someone who is in the water, especially the sea, and is in danger

something, especially a way of getting help, that you depend on to lead your life in a satisfactory way:
For many old people living on their own the phone is their lifeline to the outside world.

**Lifeline for Rovers. = A chance to save themselves**